# Octave help: tsa parcor and array handling

Tags: octave

I am a fairly novice programmer in Octave and still trying to figure out how to handle data structures. I am trying to use `acovf` from the `tsa` package with this code, getting the following error:

```
>> pkg load tsa
>> parcorr = parcor(acovf(data,5));
>> parcorr
parcorr = [](250x0)
```

Can someone explain what it means? If I try to access individual elements in the result I get the following:

```
>> parcorr(2:5)
error: A(I): index out of bounds; value 5 out of bound 0
```

Shouldn't it just give me the first 4 higher order autocorrelations in the data? Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The error message simply means that you try to access an array at a position it does not have (e.g. pos. 2/3 in an 2/2 array, or any position in an empty array). Most likely, `data` is not what you would want it to be before handing it to `acovf` (look at `numel(data)` or `size(data)` to see if it is what you expect - could be that you just messed it up and it is empty or similar).

Here's a working minimal example (compare yours to it):

```
pkg load tsa

# with 1D data
data = sin(0:0.1:100);
numel(data)
parcorr = parcor(acovf(data,5));            
plot(parcorr);

# with 2D data
data2 = [sin(0:0.1:100);cos(0:0.1:100)];
size(data2)
parcorr = parcor(acovf(data2,5));            
plot(parcorr');
```

Comment: You shouldn't recommend the use of `length` because it has a odd definition, length of the longest dimension.  `numel` should be preferred instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help. I think I have figured out the issue. Ovtave was looking for a row vector, whereas I was feeding acovf and parcor a column vector. Once I changed it to data', it worked. That is really weird that Octave is so particular about orientation of vectors.